# Truncating time to timedelta

Tags: python, date, timedelta

I'm creating a date calculator and I want to just show the days, not the time.

This is my code:

```
        daystoAdd = 2
        date_today = date.today()
        result = date_today + timedelta(days=daystoAdd)
        print('result')
```

And this is the output:

```
Sat, 18 Apr 2020 00:00:00 GMT
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify how your input looks like and how your desired output should look like?

Comment: My input in this case is 2, the output I would like would be any without the time.

Comment: Do you need the output as string or int? Why not just use `print(result.day)`?

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.date` has method `.strftime` which return `str` accoring to format `str` you provide.
Example:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
daystoAdd = 2
date_today = date.today()
result = date_today + timedelta(days=daystoAdd)
print(result.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Output:

```
2020-04-18
```

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) covering `.strftime` method codes. Note that for date, using unit smaller than day will result in zeros, for example `%M` (minutes) will result in `00` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

if the expected output is just a string, you can use strftime

Reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

```
daystoAdd = 2
date_today = date.today()
result = date_today + timedelta(days=daystoAdd)
formatted_time = result.strftime('%a, %d %m %Y')
print(formatted_time)
```

Output:

```
Sat, 18 04 2020
```

You can use this for the formatting parameter reference:
https://strftime.org/